# Getting 422 response from apache Tika with python 2

Tags: python-2.7, apache-tika, tika-server

can some one please help me to solve the mentioned error? I uninstalled the tika and reinstalled it but getting error. I don't have idea about how to solve this error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to kill apache server process or you can simply restart your machine and re-run your script

Comment: Please make sure your answer provide more information some code would be great , If you want to point to something you can use comments section